# How to do radio button validation in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my application i have two radio buttons,one text box and one button

```
    <input type="radio" name="myRadio" value="red" id="myRadio" checked>Red color
    <input type="radio" name="myRadio" value="Blue" id="myRadio">Blue color
     <input type="text" id="txtShareCount" name="txtColor"/>
<input type="submit" name="btnsubmit" value="Blue" id="btnsubmit">submit
```

Here when i check `Blue color radio button text box will appear` 
what i want is, I need to do validation for text box in jquery when i check Blue color radio button if text box is empty then click submit button it display alert message how can i do this in jquery

I did this  in javascript it works fine but I need in jquery how can i do this in jquery

Comment: First of all, don't have multiple elements with the same Id. use class for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the value of your radio use:

```
$('input[name=myRadio]:checked', '#myForm').val()
```

Or if you're not using a form

```
$('input[name=myRadio]:checked').val()
```

Answer (score 0):

For radiobutton you can use `:checked` selector - `$('#myRadio:checked')`

Answer (score 0):

Note :

1-don't have multiple elements with the same Id

2-when use getElementById , you must enter id attribute

Try this

```js
function myFunction() {
    if (document.getElementById('myRadioRed').checked == true || document.getElementById('myRadioBlue').checked == true) {
        if (document.getElementById('txtShareCount').value == "") {
            alert("Please Enter Color");
             document.getElementById("txtShareCount").focus();
              return false;
         }
         return false;
     }
     else { return true; }
}
```

```html
 <input type="radio" name="myRadio" value="red" id="myRadioRed" checked>Red color
<input type="radio" name="myRadio" value="Blue" id="myRadioBlue">Blue color
<input type="text" id="txtShareCount" name="txtColor" />
<input type="button" name="btnsubmit" value="Blue" id="btnsubmit" onclick="myFunction()"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the traditions and the documentations. Your js gets messed up if you have more than 1 element with same id. So instead of using `getElementById()` use  `getElementsByName()`

So something like this

```
function validateRadio() {
    var radios = document.getElementsByName("myRadio");
    var formValid = false;

    var i = 0;
    while (!formValid && i < radios.length) {
        if (radios[i].checked) 
           formValid = true;
        i++;        
    }

    if (!formValid) 
       alert("Must check some option!");
    return formValid;
}​
```